# Projection matrix that has y-axis facing forward

Tags: c++, opengl

I would like to switch the second and third column of the projection matrix, to have it look down the y-axis and have z facing upwards. Can I change GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Swapping two columns is not a rotation (it changes the determinant).

It is better to set up a rotation matrix (from an axis and an angle) and rotate that way.

Comment: Thanks. That did the job.